# Metamask (Chrome) web3.js console: ETH transaction issue (synchronous methods) + web3.version

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask

I am using Metamask (Chrome extension) and the web3.js API via the Google Chrome console.
However, I have two issues:

1) I am trying to send a simpletransaction using Ganache GUI (localhost 7545) and I am entering the code below:

`> ethereum.enable()`

```
> web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress

<."0xb8662b66584ae08a88341df0d2b3fa7a65eb158c"
```

```
> var transaction = {
    from: web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress,
    to: "0xA8b62F503181D9A56683129de1B98ea4Bf143a40",
    value: web3.toWei("1", "ether")
}
```

```
> web3.eth.sendTransaction(transaction)
```

Then I am getting the error message below:

```
> Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter. See https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client for details.
    at MetamaskInpageProvider._sendSync (inpage.js:1)
    at MetamaskInpageProvider.send (inpage.js:1)
    at Proxy.t.send (inpage.js:1)
    at a.send (inpage.js:1)
    at w.e [as sendTransaction] (inpage.js:1)
    at <anonymous>:1:10
```

2) Also note that the `web3.version` seems to be 0.20.7 whereas when I check this website https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/, the new version of the web3.js API seem to be 1.2.4. Is there a way to update the web3.js API version in the chrome console while using the Metamask extension? 
Note that I have tried to enter this in the console `web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)` but the `web3.version` remains 0.20.7.

In terms of priority 1) is more critical I believe.

Could you please assist.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for the first question, It's probably just exactly as the error says: Web3 object does not support synchronous methods that mean when calling web3.eth.sendTransaction you have to provide a callback so when the operation is fulfilled you will get the result in a callback because it's an asynchronous operation

this is the correct implimentation :

```
   web3.eth.sendTransaction(transaction,function(err, transactionHash) {
      if (!err)
        console.log(transactionHash); 
    }
```

for the second question, you can update the web3 that metamask provides 
include the relevant  tag for web3 js file, and then do:

```
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

- web3 will be deprecated in the near future in favor of the ethereumProvider.